# Google compute- invalid login details

Tags: google-compute-engine

Today and yesterday, I creat some windows vps server 2008 but when I tried to logging it said

> Invalid username/ password

I can sure I've typed login details correct, anyone please give me a solution?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Using the developers console, go to Compute->Compute Engine, click on your Windows VM instance, then click on "Get the command to view username and password used to create the instance".

Run the command, under 'gce-initial-windows-password' and 'gce-initial-windows-user' values you should find your initial username and password.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you are providing the correct username and password (**without any whitespace**) while connecting to server. If you are still not able to login into it, then I suggest you to reset the password of your VPS and try to connect again.

Comment: oh, thank so much! I think it's an error from google, I can sure I typed correct. Can you please tell me how to reset password? I don't find this option anywhere :(